# Social Bar is not coming above?

Tags: html, css, firefox, opera

I am trying to put bar to close to black footer its working in chrome but not in firefox and opera. The picture in chrome is like it
[image]

But in firefox and opera the social bar is down and not coming directly underneath the footer.
Live site here
http://uaepap.org/NewsEvents.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not clearing your floats. Add `overflow: hidden` to `#CopyRight`.

Here is a short article explaining why and how to clear floats - [The How and Why of Clearing Floats](http://css-tricks.com/the-how-and-why-of-clearing-floats/) by: Chris Coyier

Comment: @Hira, No problem. Just added a link explaining a little more about why you need to clear floats.

Comment: Sorry but when i do this in chrome the problem comes in chrome.

Comment: Sorry my bad its working in chrome too. Thanks for this and article Thanks it was taking alot of time of mine.

Comment: No problem at all, I'm glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are using non-interoperable code.

Validate your CSS and HTML using [W3Cs' Markup Validation Service](http://validator.w3.org/).